# How to do something while a process is running in Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, process

I'm running a process from unity and it kinda take some time(it actually can take up to 30 minutes), however I want unity to run it for maximum 5 minutes and if there was no output, return.
I also want to show something like this during this wait for 5 minutes time [image: Wait]

anybody has an idea how to do this? I tried using this line of code

```
    myProcess.WaitForExit(1000 * 60 * 5);
```

but I can't do anything while it's waiting, I guess it's blocking me or something, can anybody help?

EDITED:

```
   public void onClickFindSol(){
    paused=true;
    ReadRedFace();
    ReadGreenFace();
    ReadBlueFace();
    ReadYellowFace();
    ReadOrangeFace();
    ReadWhiteFace();
    if (File.Exists (path))
        File.Delete (path);
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path,InputToAlgo);      
    myProcess = new Process();
    myProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = (System.Environment.CurrentDirectory )+Path.DirectorySeparatorChar+"rubik3Sticker.ida2";
    myProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    myProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = (System.Environment.CurrentDirectory )+Path.DirectorySeparatorChar;
    myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "corner.bin edge1.bin edge2.bin";
    myProcess.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler((sender, e) =>
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data)){
            timer = 0f;
            StepsOfSolution++;
            print(e.Data);
            solution.output.Add(e.Data);
        }
    });
    myProcess.Start();
    myProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
}
void Update(){
    if (myProcess != null){
        if(timer>fiveMinutes){
            myProcess.Kill();
            myProcess.Close();
            badExit=true;
            myProcess=null;
            return;
        }
        timer += Time.deltaTime;
        if (!myProcess.HasExited){
            RubikScene.PleaseWait.SetActive(true);
        }
        else{
            if(badExit){
                RubikScene.PleaseWait.SetActive(false);
                RubikScene.TooLong.SetActive(true);
                print("TimeOut!");
            }else{
                paused=false;
                Application.LoadLevel("solution");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: make a timer check for output every X seconds while timer isn't above 5 minutes if it is then stop the process , no need to block anything

Comment: @user2320445 WaitForExit blocks everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use `myProcess.WaitForExit()`. It will block until it returns. Use `myProcess.Start()`, then in your Update function, run your animation inside `if !myProcess.HasExited`. Your code is incomplete so I will provide incomplete solution but this should work.

```
void Start()
{
 timer = 0;//Reset Timer
 myProcess.Start();
}
```

Check if the process has finished in the Update function

```
float timer = 0f;
float fiveMinutes = 300; //300 seconds = 5minutes
bool badExit = false;

void Update()
{
 if (myProcess != null)
 {
    //Check if Time has reached
    if(timer>fiveMinutes){
        myProcess.Kill();
        myProcess.Close();
        badExit = true;
        return;
    }
    timer += Time.deltaTime;

   if (!myProcess.HasExited)
   {
    //Do Your Animation Stuff Here
   }else{
      //Check if this was bad or good exit
      if(badExit){
        //Bad
       }else{
        //Good
        }
    }
 }
}
```

Then somewhere else in your callback function where you receive/read from the process, if the bytes read is **>0** then always reset timer to **0**. So that  the timer will only count to **5 minutes** when it has not received anything for **5 minutes**.

```
myProcess.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler((sender, e) =>
{
// Prepend line numbers to each line of the output.
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data))
 {
    timer = 0f; //Reset Process Timer
    lineCount++;
    output.Append("\n[" + lineCount + "]: " + e.Data);
 }
});
```

OR with a **callback** function

```
private static void SortOutputHandler(object sendingProcess, 
            DataReceivedEventArgs outLine)
 {
  // Collect the sort command output.
  if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(outLine.Data))
   {
      timer = 0f; //Reset Process Timer
      numOutputLines++;

      // Add the text to the collected output.
      sortOutput.Append(Environment.NewLine + 
      "[" + numOutputLines.ToString() + "] - " + outLine.Data);
   }
 }
```

Comment: It would be simpler if you set `timer = Time.time` and then use `timer < Time.time+fiveMinutes` instead of `timer = 0`

Comment: I avoid `Time.time`. It is a time that since the game started. The more the gun runs, the more that number goes up and the bugger the number. At some point, you get a really big number like this 93848589323 +fiveMinutes and no one knows when it resets. Time.deltaTime returns tiny number that requires no big number operation and it also depends on the framerate which means it will run the-same way in every device.

Comment: dude you're a lifesaver! thank you thank you thank you !

Comment: one more question, how am I supposed to know if the process ended successfully? (before the timer has finished) ?

Comment: @msLangdon95 Inside the `if(timer>fiveMinutes){`. If that is ever true then you know that you didnt receive anything for 5 seconds. Inside there , process is killed and closed and you can add other codes there that will run. Any code that is in that if statements means that something went bad. I also modified the answer so that you can check for bad and good exit in the Update function. Look where I put `if(badExit){`

Comment: I LOVE YOU DUDE THANK YOU @Programmer

Comment: @Programmer sorry If I ask too much :\ I've just tried the worst case scenario(waiting for 5 minutes) and unfortunately it resulted with this error : SystemException: No process to kill.
System.Diagnostics.Process.Close (Int32 signo)
System.Diagnostics.Process.Kill ()
do you have any idea? :(

Comment: Replace `if(timer>fiveMinutes){
        myProcess.Kill();
        myProcess.Close();
        badExit = true;
        return;
    }` with `if(timer>fiveMinutes){
        myProcess.Kill();
        myProcess.Close();
        badExit = true;
        myProcess = null;
        return;
    }`  Let me know if that solved your problem.

Comment: @Programmer you did it again mr wizard :D thanks! :D